# Explanation of C code

Tags: c

What is the meaning of the following code :

```
WORD len;  
LWORD in;  
LWORD out;

WORD buff_dlen(CBUFF *bp)
{
    return((WORD)((bp->in - bp->out) & (bp->len - 1)));
}
```

I understand that `bp->in - bp->out` means difference between the `in` and `out`, but what  relationship does it have with  `& (bp->len - 1);` ?

Comment: What is `WORD`, `LWORD` and `CBUFF` defined as?  What you have there is meaningless unless we know what these types are.

Comment: Your question is an implementation detail that I don't possibly see how we can answer within the context you provided.

Comment: The solitary `&` is the [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND), but it's impossible to predict what the function really attempts to do without knowing what these data types are.

Comment: It seems trying to preventing overflow. if the bp->len is const, `&  (bp-len -1)` effectively same as `% (bp-len -1)`.

Comment: anyway, why closed? very ridiculous ;-)

Comment: Argh. Through a simple google search, I believe I discovered the source in question: It's an embedded TCP/IP implementation. [netutil.c](http://read.pudn.com/downloads135/sourcecode/embed/573470/PDAtest/Tcpipsrc/NETUTIL.c__.htm) and [netutil.h](http://read.pudn.com/downloads135/sourcecode/embed/573470/PDAtest/Tcpipsrc/NETUTIL.h__.htm). `CBUFF` is a circular buffer, with a length that is a power of two. And _that_ is why `bp->in - bp->out` is bitwise ANDED with `bp->len - 1`. This should be reopened so we can properly clarify the question and provide this answer in more detail.

Comment: Any of "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form" can't be applied to this question. Only reasonable if close voters are non C programmer.

Comment: @9dan: The expression `a & (n-1)` is only effectively the same as `a % n` if `n` is a positive power of two. The header I link above requires this to be true of `CBUFF->len`. It is not generally true.

Answer (score 2):

The function returns the space available for reading in a ring-buffer of a power-of-two size.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator will return the logical AND (bit per bit) between your values `bp->in - bp->out` and `bp->len - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating upon my comment: I believe that this snippet comes from an embedded TCP/IP implementation, found in [netutil.c](http://read.pudn.com/downloads135/sourcecode/embed/573470/PDAtest/Tcpipsrc/NETUTIL.c__.htm). If this is correct, `CBUFF` is defined in [netutil.h](http://read.pudn.com/downloads135/sourcecode/embed/573470/PDAtest/Tcpipsrc/NETUTIL.h__.htm) as:

```
/* Default circular buffer size: MUST be power of 2 
** This definition is for initialisation only, and may be overriden to 
** create a larger or smaller buffer. To determine the actual buffer size, all 
** functions MUST use the 'len' value below, not the _CBUFFLEN_ definition */ 
#ifndef _CBUFFLEN_ 
#define _CBUFFLEN_ 0x800 
#endif 
/* Circular buffer structure */ 
typedef struct 
{ 
    WORD len;                   /* Length of data (must be first) */ 
    LWORD in;                   /* Incoming data */ 
    LWORD out;                  /* Outgoing data */ 
    LWORD trial;                /* Outgoing data 'on trial' */ 
    BYTE data[_CBUFFLEN_];      /* Buffer */ 
} CBUFF;
```

It appears as though the `in` and `out` members are offsets in the buffer, 'pointing' to the locations of the beginning of the in and out data. As this is a circular buffer, there are two possibilities when subtracting `out` from `in` (probably as a way to determine the length of the incoming data):

- `in > out`: The result is a positive number less than `len`. Thus, the bitwise `&` has no effect, as any number less than `0x800` anded with `0x7FF` is the number itself.
- `out > in`: In this case, the result is a negative number, between `0` and `-len`; the incoming data 'wraps around' the circular buffer. This is trickier as it relies on how negative numbers are represented in memory.  A few examples may help elucidate what is happening (recall that 0x800 in decimal is 2048):

```
bp->in-bp->out  |  representation  |  &'ed with 0x7FF   | decimal representation
----------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------------------
     -1         |      0xFFFF      |       0x07FF       |      2047 (2048-1)
     -2         |      0xFFFE      |       0x07FE       |      2046 (2048-2)
     -10        |      0xFFF6      |       0x07F6       |      2038 (2048-10)
     -2046      |      0xf802      |       0x0002       |      2    (2048-2046)
     -2047      |      0xf801      |       0x0001       |      1    (2048-2047)
```

As you can see, this is a simple technique to 'unwrap' the circular buffer and retrieve the effective distance between `in` and `out`.