# Help me understand this TCP/IP code snippet

Tags: c

I am reading the book "TCP/IP Lean" and I came across the following code which i do not understand. Could anyone explain it to me?

```
WORD buff_in(CBUFF *bp, BYTE *data, WORD len)
{
    WORD in, n, n1, n2;
    in = (WORD)bp->in & (bp->len-1); 
    n = minw(len, buff_freelen(bp)); 
    n1 = minw(n, (WORD)(bp->len - in)); 
    n2 = n - n1; 
    if (n1 && data) memcpy(&bp->data[in], data, n1); 
    if (n2 && data) memcpy(bp->data, &data[n1], n2); 
    bp->in += n; 
    return(n);
}
```

Comment: `CBUFF` is not a standard data type. Without knowing its structure and purpose, it is difficult to answer this question.

Comment: This really reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812391/explanation-of-c-code/.

Answer (score 0):

You really should give some more context of this code. WORD is probably 4 bytes long since this is TCP/IP internals.

It appears to have something to do with copying data from a C buffer into an IPv4 packet. The two memcpy calls, seem to be swapping around two chunks of data.

It would help if you could explain what the inputs to buff_in are supposed to represent. CBUFF is a bit misleading because it is clearly a structure of some sort. Maybe just a length byte followed by a data buffer, but it would help if you told us for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be copying up to `len` bytes of data from `data` to a circular buffer `bp`.

`bp->len` is the length of the circular buffer, and has to be a power of two, and  `bp->in` is the index within the circular buffer at which the next byte is to be written.  `buff_freelen(bp)` returns the amount of free space in the circular buffer, and `minw()` returns the minimum of the two arguments.

`n` is set to the amount of bytes to be copied, the minimum of the supplied `len` or the amount of free space in the destination buffer.  It then splits this into two chunks - `n1`, which is copied in starting at `bp->data[in]` and finishing at or before `bp->data[bp->len - 1]`, and `n2` (possibly zero length) which is copied in starting at `bp->data[0]`.

It advances `bp->in` and returns `n`, the number of bytes copied.